# Reading RFID_Presented as String Against .txt File

Tags: python, string, list, compare, rfid

I am trying to make an RFID door lock. The goal is to scan an RFID card that will check against a .txt file. Accept if the card string is in in file, play a video if the card is accepted, and then send an unlock signal.

What is happening is that every card is accepted no matter if it is loaded or not. I am not sure why this is happening... I am attaching my code if someone could please help!!!

Here is my code:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from evdev import InputDevice
from select import select
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
from time import sleep
import subprocess
from subprocess import run
import datetime
import os
import sys
import re
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

def main():
    
    pygame.init()
    windowSurface = pygame.display.set_mode ((1024, 600), pygame.NOFRAME)
    img = pygame.image.load("/home/pi/Accepted/New Phone Wallpaper copy.jpg")
    pygame.mouse.set_cursor((8,8),(0,0), (0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0), (0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0))
    windowSurface.blit(img, (0,0))
    pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.event.clear()


    def check_if_string_in_file(file_name, string_to_search):
        """Check if any line in the file contains given string"""
        with open("/home/pi/Accepted/Loaded_Cards.txt",'r') as read_obj:
            for line in read_obj:
                if string_to_search in line:
                    return True
        return False

    rfid_presented = ""    
    e = rfid_presented;

    keys = "X^1234567890asdfghjklXXXXXycbnmXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    dev = InputDevice('/dev/input/event0')

    while True:
            r,w,x = select([dev], [],[])
            for event in dev.read():
                    if event.type==1 and event.value==1:
                            if event.code==28:
                                if check_if_string_in_file('/home/pi/Accepted/Loaded_Cards.txt', e):
                                    videoPath = "myMovieFile.mp4"
                                    omx = run(["omxplayer", '--win', '1,1,1024,600', videoPath])
                                    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
                                    GPIO.setwarnings(False)
                                    GPIO.setup(26, GPIO.OUT, initial=GPIO.LOW)
                                    GPIO.output(26, GPIO.HIGH)
                                    time.sleep(3)
                                    GPIO.output(26, GPIO.LOW)
                                           
                    
                                else:              
                                    rfid_presented = ""
                                        
            else:
                            rfid_presented += keys[event.code]
                            
main()
```

Comment: `rfid_presented = ""` and `e = rfid_presented` so your check string is a blank string and that is present in each line, you need to set the value of `e` somewhere in your loop

Comment: I appreciate you helping. It seems wherever I place this, I get the same result.. I'm at a loss..

Comment: you need to set `rfid_presented` in the `while` loop (and not to `""`) before you check its value

Comment: So instead of rfid_presented =" ", I should maybe do rfid_presented()?

Comment: I keep getting an error now...local variable 'rfid_presented' referenced before assignment....